# MySQL Hosting for Windows Programs

Tags: mysql, windows, host

I'm just going to be typing my wall of text here but feel free to skip to the useful parts ^^

So basically I currently own a small website where i intend to distribute free, and possibly later on, paid software.

Now, I'm currently working on a few programs that require a database, such as a universal bug reporter for all my applications for example, also an account system and some other stuff.
This would basically mean that every IP is able to connect to the mySQL server.
Now I have a few questions:

1. Is there something that i should do to make sure that my database could not be hacked by people somehow decompiling my programs? (I'm not too sure how this works so, sorry if that sounded retarded)
2. Where would be a good place to host this mySQL server? My website is very small and currently my programs are pretty much only being used by some friends so preferably a free service, my database shouldn't become bigger than a few megabytes anytime soon, but I would like a reliable service that keeps backups though. I already considered my current web host but they don't allow remote mySQL access.
3. Is there some sort of more logical alternative, or perhaps something better than mysql (I am just a self taught noob developer so I honestly don't. I've only ever worked with mysql before)

Answer (score 0):

Do not expose your database to the internet.

You can either:

1. Use an embedded database such as sqlite if your data can be stored locally, or
2. Expose functionality on your web server via a web interface

Further reading:

- http://www.sqlite.org/
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app

Comment: Well the data can't really be stored locally. And a web interface could work for some programs but certainly not all of them. How do the professionals deal with stuff that requires a database

Comment: Hmh, I just read the page and it seems like it could work but it also seems like it's even more unsafe then shoving the database password openly in every program. What if i'd want to run an insert command and someone decompiles the program and sees how it works, couldn't they just go around shoving whatever they want into the database using the php page?

Comment: Nope, the code shown in that article executes on the web server - it cannot be seen by the user nor can it be decompiled. By contrast, if your database connection is exposed to the internet your SQL queries must exist on the client-side, in which case it's possible to decompile the code or intercept the query.

Comment: Ahh I understand, alright thanks, I'll leave this question open for a bit in the hopes that I'll get another informative answer ^^

Comment: No dramas. I suggest you might also want to read up on server-side scripting, and perhaps n-tier architectures. This is "how the pros do it" :)